# Dynamic Mysql query & passing multiple values through `GET`

Tags: php, mysql

I have a basic form that has several checkboxes. When a checkbox is checked it will append the value to a url for an ajax call. After I pass these values to `mypage.php?item1=1&item2=2&item3=3`, I am using GET[‘item’] to retrieve and store these values in order to use in an SQL query. The complexity of this problem is the amount of values passed may vary since it is based on checkboxes. For example, you can pass 1 value or pass all three values. My question is: How can I make this dynamic that would work with the sql query? If more than one value is passed, then the query would require in the `WHERE` clause an `AND` for the additional items.

```
<script>
$('#submitForm').click(function() {
    var url = "'www.mysite.com/mypage.php";
    if ($("#checkbox_form").serialize().length > 0) {
        url += "?" + $("#checkbox_form").serialize();     
    }
    $.getJSON(url)
});
</script>
<form name="checkbox_form" id="checkbox_form">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="item1" name="val1" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="2" id="item2" name="val2" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="3" id="item3" name="val3" />
    <input type="submit" id="submitForm" value="Submit Form" />
<form>
```

mypage.php?item1=1&item2=2

```
$item = $_GET['item#']; 

$sql_query = "SELECT info From Products Where :item# AND item#";
$sql_prepare = $db_con->prepare($sql_query);
if (!$sql_prepare->execute(array(':item#' => $item)))
//rest of code
```

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause seems wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to create an array of inputs instead of "val1", "val2".

Just give every input a `name` of `val[x]` like `val[1]` , `val[2]` and so on. Or you can just let it a new array element: `val[]`.

Then, you need to handle this with a PHP foreach before building the query, something like:

```
$sql_query = "SELECT info From Products";

$conditions = array();

if (isset($_GET['val']) && is_array($_GET['val'])) {
    $vals = $_GET['val'];
    foreach ($vals as $key => $val) {
        $conditions[] = '`field'. $key .'` = '. $val;
        // You should change the conditions the way you want, I'm not sure about what you want here.
    }
}

if (count($conditions) > 0) {
    $sql_query .= ' where '. implode(' and ', $conditions);
}
```

And you are done!

**UPDATE**

As discussed in the comments, this is the condition you are looking for:

```
    foreach ($vals as $val) {
        $conditions[] = '`item_id` = '. $val;
    }
```

Moreover, don't forget that you need `OR` not `AND` in this context. So, edit this line as well:

```
    $sql_query .= ' where '. implode(' or ', $conditions);
```

Comment: Alright, trying this right now. I had the same scenario with a project of mine.

Comment: So the name would be like: `<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="val[1]" name="val[1]" />`?

Comment: Exactly. if you don't need the "id" in Javascript, just eliminate it, it won't convert to a Javascript array!

Comment: okay passing the values but because i am using `[]` in the url it looks like this `www.mysite.com/mypage.php?val%5B4%5D=1`? That shouldnt be a problem right?

Comment: haha ok, In my condition i am comparing `val[]` to `item_id` and it is showing error:  `Unknown column 'item_id2' in 'where clause''`

Comment: Wait, you want something like: `where item_id = 1 or item_id = 2 or item_id = 3` this way?

Comment: My ajax call was this: `?val[1]=1&val[2]=2`

Comment: Yes that is correct. For example if there are two items `Where item_id = 1 AND item_2 = 2`

Comment: Then, before this, you don't need to set the input names to: `val[1]` , `val[2]` and so on. Just make them all: `val[]` you don't need the keys. You are going to use the value all the time. And check my update few minutes later to the answer!

Comment: I've updated the answer. Please understand and experiment it and let me know about the result!

Comment: Ok now I am getting error: `Column 'item_id' in where clause is ambiguous'`

Comment: Can you `echo` your `sql_query` and share it here?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46311/discussion-between-techaddict82-and-ashraf-samhouri)

Comment: check the chat please